# iphone: can i detect a url type?

Tags: iphone, url, uiwebview

I'm currently creating a twitter client for iphone.

Basically, I have three kinds of url types I want to handle:

- Standard URL's (e.g. http://www.msn.com)
- YouTube URL's
- URL's containing links to a stream.

When a user clicks a link.. instead of launching the web view and letting the webview decide whether to load quicktime player & youtube player, I want to be able to handle it within the app.

i.e. how can i code something like:

check link
if link = link.youtube then
   load youtube player
if link = link.mp3 stream then
   load quicktime player
else
   load in webview

Answer (score 1):

Checking youtube is easy, you can just check the domain like

```
[NSString rangeOfSubstring:@"youtube.com"].location != NSNotFound
```

The mp3 stream is not so hard, you check for the last extension by getting the last "." and then check it agains the set of video stream format like:

```
NSArray *possibleExtensions = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSString *extension = [possibleExtensions objectAtIndex:([possibleExtensions count] - 1)];  
NSSet *extensionSet = [NSSet setWithObjects: @"mp4", @"mov", @"m4v", @"mpv", @"3gp", nil];    
BOOL isStream = [extensionSet containsObject:extension];
```

If you want to check for normal link, you can use Regular expression:

```
  NSString *regrexUrl = @"\\b((?:[\\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\\s()<>]+(?:\\([\\w\\d]+\\)|(?:[^\\p{Punct}\\s]|/)))";
  // Based on http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls

  NSString *urlString = [YOUR_STRING_HERE stringByMatching:NCPARSER_REGEX_URL capture:1];
  if (urlString) {
    NSLog(@"It is an url");
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! hmm.. but say its a youtube results page.. e.g. http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=results&aq=f   ...wouldn't this return an error?

Comment: Then, you may need to detect for this whole substring : "http://www.youtube.com/watch"